# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server can't solve it

Tags: apache

Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server can't solve it.

I'm installing Asterisk and FreePBX on a CentOS7 and I came across this error that I can't solve, when I turn on Apache it won't turn on, I can't decipher where the error is,

I can't get Apache to work:

> Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

When turning on the service, the message appears:

```
[root@nsn364514433 ~]# systemctl restart httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When accessing the status, the message appears:

```
[root@nsn364514433 ~]# systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Dom 2021-12-19 04:20:48 -03; 18min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 1993 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -D FOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1993 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dez 19 04:20:47 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dez 19 04:20:48 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dez 19 04:20:48 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Dez 19 04:20:48 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Dez 19 04:20:48 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

When accessing `journalctl -xe`, the following msg is output:

```
-- Support: tp://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- A unidade session-11.scope concluiu a inicialização.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Dez 19 04:10:01 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br CROND[1944]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Dez 19 04:10:54 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br sudo[1940]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dez 19 04:11:17 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br sudo[1950]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/nano /etc/selinux/config
Dez 19 04:11:17 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br sudo[1950]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
Dez 19 04:11:26 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br sudo[1950]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dez 19 04:11:36 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br polkitd[633]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:1952:468380 (system bus name :1.78 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], ob
Dez 19 04:11:36 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unidade httpd.service sendo iniciado
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- A unidade httpd.service está sendo iniciada.
Dez 19 04:11:36 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dez 19 04:11:36 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: A unidade httpd.service falhou
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- A unidade httpd.service falhou.
--
-- O resultado é failed.
Dez 19 04:11:36 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Dez 19 04:11:36 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Dez 19 04:11:36 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br polkitd[633]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:1952:468380 (system bus name :1.78, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authent
Dez 19 04:11:45 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br polkitd[633]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:1962:469344 (system bus name :1.79 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], ob
Dez 19 04:11:45 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unidade httpd.service sendo iniciado
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- A unidade httpd.service está sendo iniciada.
Dez 19 04:11:46 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dez 19 04:11:46 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: A unidade httpd.service falhou
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- A unidade httpd.service falhou.
--
-- O resultado é failed.
Dez 19 04:11:46 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Dez 19 04:11:46 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Dez 19 04:11:46 nsn364514433.cubo.net.br polkitd[633]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:1962:469344 (system bus name :1.79, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authent
lines 2547-2594/2594 (END)
```

I don't have much knowledge so I ask for your help.

Comment: could you please share error log?

Comment: @Pandurang How do I generate this error log and how do I access it?

Comment: @Pandurang `cd /var/log/httpd/vim access_log-20211219`  follow the log:
 `172.104.131.24 - - [17/Dec/2021:00:34:34 -0300] "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ9999" 400 226 "-" "-"
205.185.124.100 - - [17/Dec/2021:01:05:09 -0300] "POST /boaform/admin/formLogin HTTP/1.1" 404 221 "http://191.101.131.33:80/admin/login.asp" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0" `

Comment: `cd /var/log/httpd/vim error_log-20211219` follow the log: 
`[Sun Dec 19 02:53:41.759962 2021] [core:emerg] [pid 992] (22)Invalid argument: AH00024: Couldn't set permissions on the rewrite-map mutex; check User and Group directives
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Sun Dec 19 02:55:06.943893 2021] [core:emerg] [pid 1432] (22)Invalid argument: AH00024: Couldn't set permissions on the rewrite-map mutex; check User and Group directives
AH00016: Configuration Failed`

Comment: @Pandurang the error logs that exist are the ones above, but I don't understand.

Comment: I've already solved the problem.